# Как улучшить глобальный хук на языке C# в Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: c#

В форме у меня есть следующий код

```
Proba3.globalKeyboardHook gkh = new Proba3.globalKeyboardHook();
void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Z);
    gkh.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyUp);
}
void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Z)
    {
        Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        currentProcess.CloseMainWindow();
        currentProcess.Close();
    }

}
```

Но хук этот ловится не всегда, например, когда у меня выполняются некоторые другие скрипты по нажатию Z ничего не произойдет. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы независимо от того, что сейчас выполняется и т.д. по нажатию на Z всегда выполнялся этот код?

Comment: Разумеется, тут все в курсе что за класс `Proba3.globalKeyboardHook` вы используете

Comment: c# это в какой-то степени надстройка над WinApi. Возможно вам поможет почитать про функцию перехвата SetWindowHookEx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx,  она имеет некоторые тонкости работы. Надо понимать что клавиатурный обработчик имеет много стадий и возможно не везде Jтот уровень перехватывает клавиши.